# print format adjust decimal point

Tags: scala, format, decimal

I like to print a lot of numbers between -1 and 1 and need them to be aligned by the decimal point.

What I get with %2.2f is:

```
val (a, b) = (0.38, -0.38); println (f"${a}%2.2f\n${b}%2.2f ")
0,38
-0,38
```

What I like to get is:

```
 0,38
-0,38
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can actually do is to add `-+` preceding the formatting likewise:

```
scala> val (a, b) = (0.38, -0.38); println (f"${a}%-+2.2f\n${b}%-+2.2f")
+0.38
-0.38
a: Double = 0.38
b: Double = -0.38
```

You will get the `+` before the number though.

**EDIT:**

If you know the number of digits of the numbers (the first number of %n.m indicates the length of the digits), you can actually go like:

```
scala> printf("%5.2f", a);
 0.38
scala> printf("%5.2f", b);
-0.38
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but not an option. I never write numbers with plus in front and nobody else I know, does. Instead of improving the visibility of negative numbers, the sign decreases the significance of a minus sign. It's anti ergonomic.

Comment: Yeah, I meanwhile found out myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although there is already an accepted answer, I'll add one more for future reference. Scala `f""` string interpolator actually uses [Java formatting infrastructure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail) and in the Java documentation you may find following flag:

> `'  '`    `'\u0020'`  Requires the output to include a single extra space (`'\u0020'`) for non-negative values.

So you might actually want to use it. Here is an example that shows the difference:

```
val arr = Array(0.38, -0.38, 10.38, -10.38, 123.38, -123.38)
println("Without space:")
arr.foreach(a => println(f"${a}%6.2f"))
println("----------------")
println("With space:")
arr.foreach(a => println(f"${a}% 6.2f"))
```

which produces following output:

```
Without space:
  0,38
 -0,38
 10,38
-10,38
123,38
-123,38
----------------
With space:
  0,38
 -0,38
 10,38
-10,38
 123,38
-123,38
```

note the difference for 123.38/-123.38 i.e. for the case when there is an "overflow"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trivial: The first number does not indicate digits before the dot, but digits total, and does not yield to an errormessage, if too short. So for 2 digits after the dot, plus dot, plus one in front and an optional minus sign, I need 5 digits in total, and then it works:

```
 val (a, b) = (0.38, -0.38); println (f"${a}%5.2f\n${b}%5.2f ")
  0,38
 -0,38
```

And no, a plus sign is not an option.